# openxlsx can't open zipped xlsx file

Tags: r, openxlsx

I use openxlsx library to load Excel workbooks and write data to them.

```R
wb <- loadWorkbook("example.xlsx")
```

The problem is openxlsx can't open some excel files. It gives me this error:

```
Error in match(sheetrId, file_rIds) : object 'sheetrId' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In unzip(file, exdir = xmlDir) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

I tried this:

```R
wb <- loadWorkbook("example.xlsx", isUnzipped = T)
```

In this case, warning is gone, but error persists.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, [report the bug](https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/new/choose): the code attempts to reference `sheetrId` when that variable has only been defined in a specific sub-path of code; it should fail more predictably, this is clearly an avoidable bug. Second, that object is not being defined because `length(workbookXML) > 0` is not true. This speaks to the real issue for you, though it could easily be indicating that _that_ `xlsx` file is corrupted (or not an `xlsx` file). I can reproduce this when it is _really_ an `xls` file, very different (but still has something `unzip` can find).

Comment: This file opens normally in excel. I don't think it's corrupted.

Comment: Assuming that `Sys.which("file")` is not empty, run `system2("file", "example.xlsx")`. If it prints something like `example.xlsx: Microsoft Excel 2007+` (or `Microsoft OOXML`), then it would seem your file is corrupt, as that is correct for `xlsx`. If instead it prints something like `example.xls: Composite Document File V2 Document`, then it would appear that your file is really `xls` (legacy, non-open) format.

Comment: It prints nothing. Because Sys.which() is empty

Comment: Being able to open it in excel is no safe indicator that it is `xlsx`: it could be XLSX, XLS, CSV, TAB, etc.

Comment: I created new xlsx file and copied all sheets from file, which is not openning. I get the same error.

Comment: Again, I don't know the real format of that file you created. How are you creating it? Are you _certain_ you explicitly set it to be of type "xlsx" in the save-as pulldown (in excel)? I'm sorry if this is obvious to you, but I have no way to know what is going on since I don't know what you're doing, what you're using, what the file contents are, etc. FYI, the fact that `Sys.which("file")` suggests that you are on windows and don't have Rtools installed; I don't know an easy way around that with windows other than installing it (not small, sorry). Windows is brain-dead that way.

Comment: Yes, I use Windows. I used Microsoft Excel 2019 to create new file. I don't have Rtools. I also tried xls format and it didn't work: same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question because I encountered the same exact error message. Turns out it was because I had the file open in Excel haha. Make sure the file is closed when opening or saving/overwriting!